# aws cli cloudformation deploy returns only 'status' string when unpermitted user run command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloudformation stack

Firstly I created it with fully privileged user:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name my-stack --template-file my-stack.yaml

Waiting for changeset to be created..

No changes to deploy. Stack my-stack is up to date
```

I have successfully done this using an account that gets all permissions all Actions '*' and all Resources '*'. It's poor security practice to give this account all these permissions so I've created a permisions with minimum policies attached and want to use that for deployment instead.

Usually cloudformation returns some error like:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123:user/user is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123:stack/my-stack/*
```

ect.

This way I know what permissions I should have add.

Now my stack stopped responding right way. And respons only with 'Status' string.

```
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name my-stack --template-file my-stack.yaml --profile User

Waiting for changeset to be created..

'Status'
```

No error reposnes.
No update stack triggered.
No events in Cloudformation > stack > events section.

Where I can find some logs or info why stack was not triggered?

Comment: "Where I can find some logs " API calls are logged in cloud trail.  I'm guessing you're missing some permission that the deploy command didn't handle well.   CloudTrail logs, which can take 5 or 10 minutes to arrive after the event, will show access denied messages in addition to logging successful commands.  " I've created a permisions with minimum policies attached" laudable goal, but tricky.  Keep at it, you'll get them all.